# apachebench (ab) -g switch append to file?

Tags: apachebench

apachebench (ab) -g switch generates graph friendly data. I'd like to have it run every x(min) in order to collect performance metrics and make a graph however every time the command runs it replaces the data in the file;

Is there a way to make it append the data to the file instead?

example: 
`ab -g /tmp/graph1 -n 25 -c 1 http://www.google.com/`

will put the graph data in `/tmp/graph1` file 
If I run it a second time however the data in there will be lost and replaced for new data; I want it to append instead and keep both runs data in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a rather simple way to make it work:

`ab -g /tmp/graph1 -n 25 -c 1 http://www.google.com/ && cat /tmp/graph1 >> /tmp/full_graph`